# Video dimensions on iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, video, html5-video

I'm building a website with a HTML5 video embedded on the homepage.  The video displays fine on desktop browsers.  It is coded to be 100% of the width of the container in which it sits and the site is responsive (bootstrap).  My issue is that on iPad, the dimensions are defaulting to small size (150px height, don't recall the width and it looks ridiculous.  I have tried to define a size within the HTML, this hasn't worked.

```
<video width="1024" height="768" poster="images/video-placer.png" controls autoplay >
<source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
```

The CSS for the video tag is width:100%; height:auto;

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Just checking the obvious here, you do have a </video> in there somewhere, right?

Comment: Perfect, that clears it up. Without seeing your whole page, it's hard to guess.

Comment: Did you have any luck? If so, can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in the past with some YouTube embeds. I solved it by adding this CSS class to my main stylesheet:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

Hope it helps you out.